# How to display in android something similar browser loading 

Tags: android, android-widget

I have to download and parse some file and put create list of object and that set of operations is long, about 5 to 10 sec. My question is how to display something similar in web browser popup loading ( like javascript). What widget to use for this ? Is there anything already done on that issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use progress Dialog....it will solve your problem